# The Push Notification System returned an Internal Server

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

Do all the steps for the notifications in ios, I add my label perfectly but when I send test notifications, it sends me "The Push Notification System returned to an Internal Server" and does not send me anything. I would like to know where my problem is. Thank you.

Comment: [I downvoted because the question may appear clear to the poster, but it is not for other readers](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: I am doing two applications with push notifications, in one it works well, I can send test notifications from the Azure portal and they reach more than half without problem, the problem lies in my other application and we follow all the corresponding steps for ios, I put my "My push notifications system returned an internal server error"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using your phone on a wifi network since you are in development. If this is the case, you may want to check that your router is not blocking the unusual ports apple uses for the apns sandbox. If this is your case you may want to try forwarding the ports: 2195 5223. You may also try turning off wifi all together and trying your cellular network instead.

And please ensure to add relevant code sample and detailed error before posting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).